# Definition of canonical divisor in terms of rational n-forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need to be able to define and calculate the canonical divisor of varieties, but most definitions I find seem to require a lot more knowledge of algebraic geometry than I have. One definition that seems reasonable to understand (and apply to some easy examples) is the following: "The canonical divisor is the zeros minus the poles of a rational n-form". The problem is that I don't know what a rational n-form is. It seems to be similar to differential forms but when I look up what these are, it's all about integration so I'm not sure if it's the same thing (and I don't want to study an entire subject just to find out it wasn't necessary).

I have an example where the canonical divisor is calculated for projective space (which is actually the only example of a canonical divisor I can find), but it's not very enlightening. So could someone explain me what a rational n-form is and how to find one explicitly for a certain variety? (I already know what a wedge product is, which seems to be necessary.)

Comment: In the context of compact Riemann surface and the Riemann Roch theorem, see [this p.9](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Talovikova.pdf) the divisor of a meromorphic differential is a canonical divisor, allowing us to look at the bijection $f \mapsto f \omega$. For varieties the idea should be similar.

Comment: Let $X$ be a smooth variety of dimension $n$. Then, there exists rational differential forms (called 1-forms) $\omega_i, 1\leq i\leq n$ such that $\omega_1\wedge\cdots\wedge \omega_n\neq 0$. This is a rational $n$-form.

Comment: But I still don't understand a few things. First of all, I thought the canonical divisor is also defined for non-smooth varieties (if I'm correct, the definition of a .log pair requires the canonical divisor to be defined for any normal variety). Second, how do you actually find these 1-forms? Also, is this actually the same wedge product as the one in the Plücker embedding? Because it doesn't seem to involve vectors.